# Is foreach with reference faster than without in PHP?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

Please consider these 2 codes:

Key lookup:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
   $array[$key] = "New Value";
}
```

Reference:

```
foreach ($array as $key => &$value){
    $value = "New Value";
}
// Make sure no unwanted changes are committed through this reference
unset($value)
```

My understanding of this is, that the first example with key lookup will be slower due to additional hash table lookup operation. Is this correct? Is using reference better option?

Comment: Set up a test and prove it yourself.... create a large array, run the loops, time it, and see which is faster.

Comment: I was hoping for an explanation on how array values are accessed in each case, not just the speed test.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/2mEKJ/vld#output https://3v4l.org/ghJhE/vld#output --- check opcodes, it should give some clue.

Comment: Your reference loop should be `foreach ($array as &$value){}`, otherwise it still fetches the key? Either way the performance between the two is negligible, what is far more important is what is happening ***in*** the loop. Also, i think unsetting `$value` is not needed, because it is defined in the `foreach` loop, making it have a local scope.

Comment: @Xorifelse, fyi,  [“Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().”](https://alephnull.uk/call-unset-after-php-foreach-loop-values-passed-by-reference).

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks for refreshing my memory, I forgot about it but something was nagging that it could be correct, hence the "I think". Still is an issue in PHP 7 sadly..